# How to deal with authentication in a micro-services architecture

Tags: microservices, grpc

I am currently reading a lot about microservices but still, I don't understand some parts. I made the following draw:

[image]

Each microservice has 2 accesses:

- REST: For http uses
- gRPC: For intra/background communication/exchanges

If I want to login I can just send an Http Request to my Authentication service. But what about if I want to access the Stuff service that needs you to be already connected?

Let say that the user wants to display the stuff available in the database STUFF, the service Stuff will first check if the "token" of the connected user is right, by exchanging with the Authentication service, and then return the stuff or a "login requires request".

So the thing I don't understand is, if each services that needs a client already connected needs to exchange with Authentication, then it will create a huge internet traffic in order to check each user request.. So I though about make one Authentication service per service, but since I should have only one Database, then it's the database that will slow the traffic?

Also, if I understand, each micro service should be on separate servers, not the same one?

I hope I am clear, don't hesitate to ask for more details !

Thanks in advance :)

Max

## Edit 1

**Based on @notionquest's answer:**

So it should more looks like that right?

[image]

Also, based on Peter's comment, each service can implement its own middleware (JWT as mentioned) so the API Gateway is only a "pass-through". However, I don't feel like it could be a nice for me since each service make a token check for each internal exchange, doesn't it?

For the stuff, it's easy since it checks only 1 time the token. Now, let's say that, after the user got the stuff, he choose one and wanna buy it. Then the "Buying service" will call the stuff service in order the verify the price of the item, but... It will have to check the user token since the stuff is a "on authenticated access", so it means that "Buying" service and "Stuff" service both check the token, which add an extra check.

I though about an internal guaranteed access between services but is it worth it?

Also, maybe you said to implement the middleware for each service since they have a REST access, but the API Gateway would just destroy the idea of having REST access

Comment: Don't underestimate how much a single authz/authn service can handle. In practice it just looks up single database rows by primary key. A popular alternative is JWT. But before you jump on the Microservice train be aware that they solve *organizational* problems but create technical problems -- lots of them. Don't do it because it's modern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I don't do it because it's modern, I have a real need behind :) I read about JWT and I already used it in Monolith approach, but still, I have to share the service that does the JWT check between each service.. I am just worrying about the internet traffic exchange, I don't want a service that gets too many request slows the others services :/

Comment: JWT are cryptographically signed specifically so you *don't* have to check in with anyone. They are self contained proofs.

Comment: @Peter little update based on your answer and notionquest

Comment: https://dev.to/s2agrahari/authentication-between-microservices-part-i-3dpp

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple solutions available for this problem. One of the solution is [API Gateway pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/security-in-microservices).

1. First request goes to API gateway
2. API Gateway authenticates & authroizes the request
3. Authentication is stored on cache database such as Redis, Memcache etc with expiry time on it
4. Saved access token is returned to client
5. Client can use the saved access token in the subsequent calls for the some time span (i.e. until the token is valid)
6. Once the token is expired, the API gateway will authenticate and share the new token to client
7. This solution will reduce the need to authenticate each request and improves the performance

API Gateway is the single entry point for all the services. So, you may not need separate cache for each service.

Refer the diagram in this [page](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It means then that each service should have it own tokenisation cache? So it doesn't have to communicate with the authentication service

Comment: Updated the answer. API gateway is the single entry point for all services. So, you may not need separate cache for each service.

Comment: Ok I see interesting ! But so now, the API gateway has to handle all of the requests which turns to act like a monolith approach, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it is not a monolithic app. It is an additional layer in front of all the services to perform common tasks like authentication, aggregation etc. I think you would get more understanding if you can read the full blog.

Comment: I made a little update based on your answer and peter's one

Answer (score 5):

Apart from @notionquest answer, there is another approach which does not involve having an API gateway;

You can share a `SESSION_SECRET` among all your services, so the only task of your Authentication Service is to validate username and password against the database and then encrypt this information using `SESSION_SECRET` and return a [jwt token](https://jwt.io/). All other services won't need to interact with Authentication Service but simply check if the jwt token is valid (can be decrypted) with the `SESSION_SECRET`.

You then have two other options;

1. Store all user data you need in the token - this will increase the amount of data in transit from your client to the micro-services. This can be prohibitive depending on the size of this information
2. You can store only the userId, and request additional data as needed per each micro service, which depending on how often/how big your data is will generate a problem as you described.

Note that you will not always be able to use this approach but depending on your specific scenario and requirements having this architecture in mind can be useful.

Also keep in mind that rotating the `SESSION_SECRET` can be tricky (although necessary for security reasons). AWS has just released a service called [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/secrets-manager/), so one idea to make things simple would be to have your micro-services periodically query a service like this for the current valid `SESSION_SECRET` instead of having this values hardcoded or as environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the answer. I feel like, with all of your answers (and since I ain't working in security programming at all) that finally, each approach stays unsecured.. And can be reverse engineered really easy :/

Comment: You are welcome, @Emixam23 Can you elaborate a little more on why you fell it is unsecure?

Comment: It's not the main purpose of the initial question but, let's say I have a JWT token that I encrypt with a given key. It means that anyone can use this token in order to access each APIs and then do whatever they want. What I would like is to have some public MS and some private ones. For the private one, I wanna be sure it's someone from my app and not someone else. If it's just a JWT token that transit, then the token can be intercepted by a packet capture and reused :/

Comment: Thats right. But thats true for most websites in the web. If anyone acquire access to your session cookie for example, then anyone will be able to impersonate your self. Thats why people use https currently. But I understand your concerns.

Comment: With https packets can't be intercepted?

Comment: They can, but the eavesdropper wont be able to decrypt them and thus access its contents.

Comment: Also if you want to have private micro services (in the sense that they are not open to the web) then you should go with an API Gateway. Amazon AWS provides a service for this specific purpose, you might want to have a look.